# Is it possible to modify a range variable?

Tags: cplex, opl

I need to solve a model in which I have an array with a size of 1..118 but I only want to solve it for some values (e.g. 1..9,11..60,62..115 and 117..118). The numbers that I excluded are the ones that I don't want to solve the problem for, because they will return a solution with no value and therefore are not of interest to me.

It's not possible for me to change the original array since I'll be using it to solve the relaxed version of the problem with the positions not taken before.

Is there any possible way of doing this?

Comment: Would it be an option to use a set instead of an array? A set can have holes and you can use a set almost everywhere you can use an array.

Comment: It might be. Is it possible to use the set values in the arrays while in a forall cicle?

Comment: Not sure I got your question correctly. What you can do is write `forall (i in I)`. For this `I` can any collection, an array or a set.

Comment: Yeah that's basically it. I want that `I` to be from 1..9, 11..60, etc.

Comment: `{int} I = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12 };`   `dvar int+ x[I];`    `forall (i in I) x[i] >= i; ` is a short example for this. There are also some functions like `symdiff`, `union`, `inter`, `diff` that make it easier to define sets. See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllang_quickref/topics/opl_keywords_top.html

Comment: Thank you I'm going to try to apply that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let me give you an example on how to set a range through flow control in OPL:

You have a first model sub.mod

```
int minOfx = ...;
int maxOfx = ...;
range r=minOfx..maxOfx;
dvar float x1 in r;
dvar float x2 in r;

maximize x2-x1;
subject to {

}

execute
{
writeln("x2-x1= ",x2-x1);
}
```

and then you have your main model

```
main {
  var source = new IloOplModelSource("sub.mod");
  var cplex = new IloCplex();
  var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(source);



  for(var k=1;k<=10;k++)
  {
  var opl = new IloOplModel(def,cplex);

  var data2= new IloOplDataElements();
  data2.minOfx=(k-1)*(k-1);
  data2.maxOfx=k*k;
  opl.addDataSource(data2);
  opl.generate();

  if (cplex.solve()) {  
     opl.postProcess();

  } else {
     writeln("No solution");
  }
 opl.end();
}  

}
```

When you run your main model you'll get

```
x2-x1= 1
x2-x1= 3
x2-x1= 5
x2-x1= 7
x2-x1= 9
x2-x1= 11
x2-x1= 13
x2-x1= 15
x2-x1= 17
x2-x1= 19
```

Using flow control you can change some data in a model and that can change a range.